# Countsort causing segment fault

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

Im trying to implement a count sorting algorithm in C but I ran into a weird issue.

Basically with the input of

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 6 7 7 8 10 10 10 10 10 8 8 9 9 9 9
```

My code will cause a segment fault a cloud build but not on my actual PC rather on
I cannot debug the cloud build but it works completely fine on my PC and delivers the desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "introprog_countsort.h"
#include "arrayio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        count_array[input_array[i]]++;
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int count_array[], SortDirection order) {
    int output_idx = 0;
    int max = output_array[0];
    output_array[0] = 0;
    if (order == ASCENDING) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (count_array[i] == 0) {
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < count_array[i]; j++) {
                    output_array[output_idx++] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = max - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (count_array[i] == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < count_array[i]; j++)
                    output_array[output_idx++] = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void count_sort(int input_array[], int len, int output_array[], SortDirection order) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        output_array[i] = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        max = input_array[i] > max ? input_array[i] : max;
    output_array[0] = max + 1; // PRO GAMER MOVE
    int count_array[max + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
        count_array[i] = 0;
    count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, count_array);
    count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, count_array, order);
}

/* Ab hier Funktion extract_order_direction implementieren */
SortDirection extract_order_direction(char *order) {
    SortDirection direction = NOTDEFINED;
    if (strcmp(order, "desc") == 0)  direction = DESCENDING;
    if (strcmp(order, "asc") == 0)  direction = ASCENDING;
    return direction;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int input_array[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6,
        7, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9
    };
    int len = 30;

    printf("Unsortiertes Array:");
    print_array(input_array, len);

    int output_array[MAX_LAENGE];
    count_sort(input_array, len, output_array, ASCENDING);

    printf("Sortiertes Array:");
    print_array(output_array, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code I tried
Apparently the issue is caused due to count_array but I have no idea how to potentially solve this

```
int *count_array = malloc((max + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

I tried to assign `count_array` like this but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: If you cannot run it through a debugger then utilize lots of printing of variable values everywhere. My guts say it's some 90% probability that this is an array out-of-bounds bug.

Comment: I tried and I literally cannot find it 
The output is correct 
No errors or warnings are ever raised 
I have no idea whats wrong
I checked and nothing should go out of bounds

Comment: You won't likely find the problem by staring intently at the code though. Normally you'd single step through it in a debugger. If that's not an option, then use verbose printing everywhere to show the values of all variables.

Comment: @ffcfd This code snippet  int max = 0;   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        max = input_array[i] > max ? input_array[i] : max;
    output_array[0] = max+1; // PRO GAMER MOVE
    int count_array[max + 1]; does not make sense.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX_LAENGE`?

Comment: The value of MAX_LAENGE is decided by the cloud build I currently have it as 30 and max value at 0

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What do you mean ? It doesnt make sense ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Lundin as I said I cannot do that on the cloud 
I did so on my pc and everything seems to be working fine 
I have no issues here its just that the cloud build fails

Comment: @ffcfd You have an array of integers that can have negative values.  Also this statement output_array[0] = max+1; is unclear and redundant.

Comment: @ffcfd And the function count_sort should be declared like void count_sort(int input_array[], size_t len, SortDirection order)l that is with three parameters. The function sorts the passed array. So why is there output_array present?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was given that function signature I am not allowed to change it

Comment: Can you be sure that the error occurs with the specific test input given in your `main()` function, or does the tester perhaps exercise your function with a variety of inputs?

Comment: Can you edit your question and quote the challenge literally, with all the information about max size and constraints of the inputs?

Comment: This isn't the problem you are writing about, but the "descending" code in `count_sort_write_output_array` is slightly wrong because the loop terminates before it processes `count_array[` 0 `]`.

Comment: While many things may go wrong with your code, for these particular inputs it should be fine as long as MAX_LAENGE is sufficiently large. You can drop your `if` checks in `count_sort_write_output_array` by the way, since when `count_array[i] == 0`, the `for` loop won't do anything anyway. In the same vain, initial zeroing of `output_array` is unnecessary, the array is overwritten not long afterwards. Your `output_array[0] = max + 1` trick severely hinders understanding. Better pass `max + 1` as  a separate argument which should mean the size of `count_array`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to expect your `count_sort()` function to fail with the particular inputs provided by your `main()`. But an automated judge would typically run multiple inputs against that function, some of them exercising the various implicit and explicit extrema that the function is expected to accommodate.  Issues with your sort function that could be triggered by other inputs include at least:

- The input array has elements of type `int`, which can take negative values.  Using input elements directly as indexes into `count_array` will result in an out-of-bounds accesses when elements are negative.
- `count_array` is declared in `count_sort()` as a variable-length array (1) with dimension `max + 1` (2).  Not all C implementations support VLAs, and even for those that do, it would be pretty easy to provide an input that would require `count_array` to be too large for the stack.
- saving one argument to function `count_sort_calculate_counts()` by conveying the length of the counts array inside the output array (your "PRO GAMER MOVE") is obfuscatory and gains little of value.  I would not expect to see such a thing from a *bona fide* professional programmer, and it would not pass code review with me.
- the expression `max + 1` is at risk for integer overflow.
- if `max` is very large then your program may run much more slowly than it could do.